# Convert a List of Dates as String to PANDAS DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a PANDAS Series of dates (as strings) and frequencies as integers:

```
date    
2020-02-02  24
2020-02-03  43
2020-02-07  465
2020-02-08  123
2020-02-09  234
```

But I need them as the output of *events* in the code below:

```
all_days = pd.date_range('1/01/2020', periods=300, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 200)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)
```

I mean to keep my data but change the type so that I can use them in another piece of code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would adding a second column and converting them there work?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to work with PANDAS Series, there is no column name, nothing.

Comment: Just add it to your dataframe before making the Series

Comment: If you just need a random row, you can randomly choose from the index and then map that back into your DF.

Comment: You can use the pandas.to_datetime to convert the index that is as str to date. You can acess the index making dataframe.index
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me. I did like the code below:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calmap')))
import pandas as pd
import calmap

all_days = pd.date_range('1/01/2020', periods=300, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 200)
date_index = pd.to_datetime(dates_count.index)
maximum = max(dates_count.values)
minimum = min (dates_count.values)
events = pd.Series(((dates_count.values-minimum)*2/(maximum - minimum))-1, index=date_index)
```